# Granular error reporting in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I am not sure how to pose this question. Sorry if this is already asked somewhere else: I want to log PHP errors on screen and warnings and above in a log file. Is there a way in PHP itself to set this or do I need to program a class as error handler that decides where to log?

Comment: Check out the docs here http://php.net/manual/ro/function.set-error-handler.php and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use set_error_handler(). You can catch the level of an error, therefore decide whether to show up or log to file.

FYI, [php error handling](http://php.net/manual/de/book.errorfunc.php)